# Initialize model with a default attribute that assigns from other attribute

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

The Time model has two defaults attributes duration and remainingTime and I need that remainigTime values will depend to the duration.

```
class Time extends Backbone.Model
    defaults:
      duration: 0
      remainingTime: @duration  //This don't work
```

How can I access duration value for assign it to remainingTime?

PD: In addition I tested with `Time.duration, Time.defaults.duration, this.duration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access it like that because when the defaults object will be evaluated, your context won't be your object (rather the global object). Therefore *remainingTime* will certainly be undefined.
You could do it in the *initialize* method though.

Answer (score 0):

I use a way like this: create a js(or coffee) which keeping global variables. so, it is following that:

```
root = @
#and
$ ->
  root.duration # or your other global variables
```

after than you can call the variable everywhere.